# Android getText from EditText return NULL

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

in this simple Application of my first program in Android i want to get `username` and `password` from User. but after click on button that return `NULL` and thats incorrect, `username` and `password` fields have string and are not `NULL`.
`Textusername` and `Textpassword` in this code are `NULL` and can not get string from `R.id.username` AND `R.id.password`

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/EnterUsername"
                />
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/username"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/EnterPassword"
                />
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/password"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/submitButton"
            android:text="@string/SubmitButton"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/purple"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**My Code:**

```
package com.example.AndroidMultiPage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        Button   submit   = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.submitButton);

        final String Textusername = username.getText().toString();
        final String Textpassword = password.getText().toString();

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(
                         MyActivity.this, Textusername, 
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //TOAST SHOW NULL
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please move this

`final String Textusername = username.getText().toString();
 final String Textpassword = password.getText().toString();`

inside `onClick()`.

Comment: thanks. after that i get this error `Unfortundately SimpleIntent has Stoped`

Comment: Then please post the logcat.

Answer (score 2):

You should move

```
 final String Textusername = username.getText().toString();
 final String Textpassword = password.getText().toString();
```

under `onClick(..)` of submit `Button` and inside `onClick(..)` you should check `String` values are `NULL` or not. as @Raghunandan said...

Answer (score 1):

Move this

```
String Textusername = username.getText().toString();
String Textpassword = password.getText().toString();
```

inside `onClick`.

ALso check

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(Textusername))
{
           // display Toast 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final String Textusername = username.getText().toString();
        final String Textpassword = password.getText().toString();

        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, Textusername, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


     @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                   String Textusername = username.getText().toString();

                    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, Textusername, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //TOAST SHOW NULL
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this:
 submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
String text_user=username.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(
                         MyActivity.this, text_user, 
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
        });
```